# Universal quantifier over an uncountable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, model-theory, philosophy

To prove that a segment has the same number of points with half a segment one might say that one can find a bijective function mapping every point from the segment to the half segment. Let' say:
$$\forall x\in(0,1), f(x)=x/2 $$
At first, it might seem that this argument holds because of the bijective function. However, the more I think about it, it seems that there is an implicit assumption being made when saying *for any x in (0,1)*, because this might imply a way of choosing every point in the set, which cannot be necessarily taken for granted.

Of course, I understand that one simply assumes that $\forall x \in (0,1)$ is possible, but I can't shake off the feeling this might not be such a trivial assumption. Can you think of any field of mathematics or mathematical logic or philosophy which engages with this assumption?

Comment: The axiom of choice is more about choosing a single point from each set over an infinite collection of sets. To choose a single point from a single set, you just need "finite choice". Maybe this helps: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32538/finite-axiom-of-choice-how-do-you-prove-it-from-just-zf If the set is nonempty, then you know there is some $x$ in it. We therefor also know that $x/2$ exists by real number complete ordered field theory etc. And that goes both ways. So we have a bijection. Maybe I am missing something technical though.

Comment: My question is not about choosing a single point, but rather how one can choose (or go through) every single point in the set. This proof is supposed to show that the two sets have the same cardinality because every single point from one set is mapped to a point in the other. From a mathematical perspective this is sufficient, but from a logical or philosophical perspective there seems to be an extra assumption. I was wondering if there is any literature on this assumption, or anything related.

Comment: Even from a logical perspective, nothing more is needed. That's the magic of the universal quantifier, the logical rules for manipulating it are an abstraction, a stand-in, for any particular method of going through the elements. As long as you follow the logical rules for its use, it *does not* require you to have a method for going through the elements one-by-one. There might well be other more restrictive versions of universal quantifiers in other forms of logic, but I don't know.

Comment: I agree about the "magic" of the universal quantifier because it makes the proofs so much simpler and powerful. At the same time, in this case, it seems that it actually might hide something about the structure of the sets to which it is applied. It is easy to say what $\forall x \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ means and then just say one generalizes this to $\forall x \in (0,1)$, but I can't shake off the feeling that there is a lot baked in this generalization.

Comment: I removed my answer, since the revision question and the discussion around it clearly show that the answer was answering something else. I will try to find time to edit it and answer your actual question later.

Comment: It sounds like you're thinking of interpreting universal quantifiers "offensively" in the sense that they impose upon us to make several "attacks:" to prove $\forall x\varphi(x)$ we need to separately prove $\varphi(a)$ for each relevant object $a$. However, the usual interpretation - even in "resource-sensitive" settings - is instead "**defensive**:" A proof of $\forall x\varphi(x)$ consists of a strategy for verifying $\varphi(a)$ *after* an imagined opponent has proposed a candidate counterexample $a$. At no point do we have to sift through the entire universe of relevant objects ourselves!

Comment: @NoahSchweber - That's a really nice way of putting it!

Comment: This means that we can "resource-sensitively" prove (some) universal statements even in "very rich" universes: as an admittedly-somewhat-trivial example, regardless of what setting we're living in, in order to ("defensively") prove $$\forall x(x=x)$$ we just need the ability to tell that things are equal to themselves (cf. the term "$\mathsf{refl}$" if you're familiar with LEAN). This single strategy then works regardless of what candidate counterexample our imagined opponent brings to the table.

Comment: @NoahSchweber That's a nice analysis, and I indeed considered some interpretations similar to the offensive attack along the lines of Brouwer's intuitionism or constructivism. While the "defensive" approach is a nice way of explaining the proof, it's still somewhat unsatisfactory. It feels a bit like saying: it works as long as no one can find a counterexample. In this case, we don't need to worry about what happens when we generalize $\forall x$ in a finite set to an uncountable set. That's fine, but I'm still curious to know if someone has tried to describe what's behind this generalization.

Comment: "it works as long as no one can find a counterexample." That's exactly missing the point: the point is that we can **prove** that our strategy works, regardless of what strategy our opponent employs. It isn't just a reflection of our current state of knowledge.

Comment: It feels like the question here could also be asked about a really large finite set too. $\forall x\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$ for $N$ being something like Rayo's number.  We'd never actually be able to check all $x$. This is maybe only a problem for someone with a hard core intuitionist mindset though. I'd love to see some references that discuss this the "philosophy of universal quantification", especially over large sets as that seems to be what OP is asking for. Where in the literature might this be addressed? Set theory? Philosophy of language? Philosophy of mathematics? Frege? Russell?